# How can I fix string to date error simpledateform

Tags: java

```
String from = "2019.03.03";
SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"); 
Date n = fDate.parse(from);
```

It has unhandled exception type ParseException "`fDate.parse`(from)" this line

How can I fix this code

Comment: Add a try-catch block arround this code.

Comment: The other thread uses Thread.sleep, not SimplateDateFormat#parse, but they both yield the same compiler error.

Comment: Oh, and please, use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from the `java.time` package, instead of `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, which are obsolete. [This is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Answer (score 0):

The error says we need to handle "if" a parse exception is thrown.
To handle exception, we can use try-catch block, like this:

```
try {
    String from = "2019.03.03";
    SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"); 
    Date n = fDate.parse(from);
    System.out.println(n);  
} catch(ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```